# Issue while upgrading SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, upgrade

When I tried to upgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012 everything went well except below issue

[image]

How do I fix it? Do I need to uninstall SQL Server 2012 again?

**EDIT**

```
Feature:                       Reporting Services - Native
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     The upgrade process for SQL Server failed. Use the following information to resolve the error, and then repair your installation by using this command line: setup /action=repair /instancename=MSSQLSERVER
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84BB0001
  Error description:             Service 'SQLSERVERAGENT' stop request failed.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60&EvtType=0x2E920AA9%400xD3BEBD98%401211%401&EvtType=0x2E920AA9%400xD3BEBD98%401211%401

  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     The upgrade process for SQL Server failed. Use the following information to resolve the error, and then repair your installation by using this command line: setup /action=repair /instancename=MSSQLSERVER
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84BB0001
  Error description:             Service 'SQLSERVERAGENT' stop request failed.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60&EvtType=0x2E920AA9%400xD3BEBD98%401211%401&EvtType=0x2E920AA9%400xD3BEBD98%401211%401

  Feature:                       Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     The upgrade process for SQL Server failed. Use the following information to resolve the error, and then repair your installation by using this command line: setup /action=repair /instancename=MSSQLSERVER
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84BB0001
  Error description:             Service 'SQLSERVERAGENT' stop request failed.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60&EvtType=0x2E920AA9%400xD3BEBD98%401211%401&EvtType=0x2E920AA9%400xD3BEBD98%401211%401

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     The upgrade process for SQL Server failed. Use the following information to resolve the error, and then repair your installation by using this command line: setup /action=repair /instancename=MSSQLSERVER
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84BB0001
  Error description:             Service 'SQLSERVERAGENT' stop request failed.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60&EvtType=0x2E920AA9%400xD3BEBD98%401211%401&EvtType=0x2E920AA9%400xD3BEBD98%401211%401
```

**Edit: Error while reparing it**

```
    SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

The specified value 'Repair' is invalid. To run in unattended mode, you must specify a valid ACTION. The valid values for ACTION are: '
None
RemovePatch
Uninstall
Install
Upgrade
Patch
Repair
LandingPage
ClusterReport
RunRules
PrepareFailoverCluster
CompleteFailoverCluster
InstallFailoverCluster
RemoveNode
AddNode
EditionUpgrade
Bootstrap
ComponentUpdate
Help
RebuildDatabase
RunDiscovery
PrepareImage
CompleteImage
ConfigureImage'
```

command I have used

> D:/myfolder/setup.exe /q /ACTION=Repair /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER

**After Repair**

[image]

Comment: Instead of screenshot, better to post the exact error message !

Comment: Check your error logs (which should be linked in the screen).  Your logs will be located under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log`.

Comment: The information you posted is from the summary.  You're going to have to dig in to the details for the exact error text.

Comment: Are you able to stop SQL Server Agent from the services.msc?
I'd try to stop it manually and then run the upgrade.

Comment: My upgrade is already finished. Do you mean that I have to stop SQL Server agent and then my upgrade wizard again?

Comment: @MikeFal I am not able to find more information about that issue. Can you tell me where I need to look to get more details about it?

Comment: Your database engine services upgrade failed. You'll need to repair it by running setup /action=repair /instancename=MSSQLSERVER after fixing the problem that caused it to fail in the first place.

Comment: I did the same but I am getting error which I have copied in my edit section of question.

Comment: if I double click on setup.exe and click on repair.. will that be the same thing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try to stop it manually (stop SQL Server Agent from the services.msc) and then repair.

Your database engine services upgrade failed. You'll need to repair it by running setup /action=repair /instancename=MSSQLSERVER after fixing the problem that caused it to fail in the first place.

Comment: +1 and thanks for the solution.. I have did the same and it resolved everything except reporting services - Native (i have attached the screenshot in my question).. Any Suggestion how to resolve this?

Comment: Also, I would be glad if you could answer my another question http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58204/upgrading-to-sql-server-2012-from-sql-server-2008 as I have almost no knowledge about upgrade