# Upgrading to SQL Server 2012 from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, upgrade

I have upgraded my SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition to SQL Server 2012. Even after upgrade I can see & use SQL Server 2008 R2 instance without any issue. Did my upgrade went fine?

I can open default instance both from SQL Server 2008 and 2012. Also I have updated the compatibility level of all databases to 110.

After in-place upgrade

[image: screenshot]

**Edit - version**

After running

```
SELECT @@Version
```

**SQL Server 2012**

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
    Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

**SQL Server 2008 R2**

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)   
    Feb 10 2012 19:39:15   
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Comment: Was it an inplace upgrade? What do you mean by `can open default instance both from SQL Server 2008 and 2012` ?

Comment: yes it was an in place upgrade and I am able to open both SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2012. Even when I am writing ssms.exe on run it is opening SQL Server 2008 R2 and not 2012..

Comment: It is not possible as you might be overlooking some obvious stuff. Open `configuration manager` and check what service is running.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot (programs installed) after in-place upgrade.

Comment: @Kin I am able to work both on SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012 without any issue. Does it mean that my upgrade went wrong ?

Comment: Please check `configuration manager` -- check the service and run a `select @@version`  and post the results. When you say connect - you are using ssms either 2008r2 or 2012. It does not matter. What matters is the version and the service running. Please check and let me know.

Comment: @Kin That make sense to me :) let me post output of both version of sql server

Comment: @Kin you are right.. they both are identical, which means that no matter which SSMS version I use I will surely be working on SQL Server 2012, right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning my comments to answer :

SSMS is just a tool to connect to SQL Server.

You did an inplace upgrade, but were connecting to SQL Server 2012 using SSMS 2008R2 and SSMS 2012.

Using T-SQL - will give you the correct version:

```
SELECT
   SERVERPROPERTY ('MachineName') AS PhysicalMachineName,
   SERVERPROPERTY ('ServerName') AS SQLServerName,
   SERVERPROPERTY ('Edition') AS ServerEdition,
   CAST(SUBSTRING(@@Version,charindex('SQL',@@version, 1),15) AS VARCHAR(255)) +  ' + ' 
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel')AS VARCHAR (50)) + ' + (Build'
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR (50)) +')' AS ProductVersion,
    RIGHT(@@version, (Len(@@Version)-charindex('Windows',@@version, 1))+1) AS [O.S.],
 SERVERPROPERTY ('Collation') AS Collation
```

Best practice:

- Before upgrade - run the above script to get the version and after upgrade, run it to make sure that you are on correct right version.
- Always use the latest version of SSMS (regardless of SQL Server version).

Comment: So basically, my installation went well, it is just upgrade didn't uninstall older IDE. Am I correct ?

Comment: The upgrade wont uninstall the older version, just will overwrite the binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with 2005 - 2008 R2 upgrade. The solution was to right-click the SSMS icon, and select Find Target. It proved that it still used the old SSMS (2005) instead of the new one. This might be the case for you as well.
As for being able to access both 2008 R2 and 2012... that's a bit strange.